Oracle SQL: How to Iterate through child records of a parent table and return data from the parent table based on data in the child table?
Parent Table



Parent ID
Parent Name




1
Parent A


2
Parent B



Child Table



Parent ID
Child ID
Status




1
Child A1
ACTIVE


1
Child A2
INACTIVE


2
Child B1
INACTIVE


2
Child B2
INACTIVE



How can i write a SQL query(PL/SQL?) so that i return details from the parent table only when ALL the child table child statuses are INACTIVE?
Expected output



Parent ID
Parent Name




2
Parent B



Any suggestions how to solve this in Oracle SQL will help
Thanks
Noob in SQL, any suggestions or ideas on how to proceed would help

You can join the two tables and use a GROUP BY clause with HAVING.
There you will use a conditional COUNT.
This makes sure that no row at all of the current child has a status <> INACTIVE:
SELECT 
  p.Parent_ID,
  p.Parent_Name
FROM Parent p
INNER JOIN Child c
  ON p.Parent_ID = c.Parent_ID
GROUP BY
  p.Parent_ID,
  p.Parent_Name
HAVING 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN c.Status <> 'INACTIVE' THEN 1 END) = 0;

If you don't need any data from the child table in your result, you can remove the JOIN and rather use an IN clause. This could be faster.
SELECT 
  Parent_ID,
  Parent_Name
FROM Parent p
WHERE 
  Parent_ID
  IN (
    SELECT Parent_ID
    FROM child
    GROUP BY Parent_ID
    HAVING 
      COUNT(CASE WHEN Status <> 'INACTIVE' THEN 1 END) = 0);

See this db<>fiddle with your sample data.
